How to deploy large contracts in foundry
I'm encountering an issue when deploying a smart contract on the Ethereum blockchain using Foundry. Specifically, I'm getting the following error message:
Error: 'Unknown0' is above the contract size limit (35420 > 24576). Do you wish to continue?
If I choose to continue, the transaction fails with the following message:
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [max code size exceeded].
However, I'm confused because I've seen other developers submit larger contracts during bug bounty programs, and even though their contracts are bigger than mine, they don't seem to run into these issues during deployment. After auditing and reviewing the contracts, they aren't modified in a way that could impact the contract size either.
How is it possible to deploy larger contracts on Ethereum, especially using Foundry, without hitting the "max code size exceeded" error? Are there any specific techniques or considerations that allow for larger contract deployments?

You can set the local chain/mainnet fork code size limit with:
# Increase the local smart contract code size limit to 64kb
anvil --code-size-limit 65000

More in Anvil reference manual here.

You can use the --optimize and --optimizer-runs Compiler Options with your forge build command, like:
forge build --optimize --optimizer-runs 200

This may help reduce the size of the compiled contract code.
Additionally, to further minimize contract code size, consider following the best practices, like:

Adhere to the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.
Use constant and immutable variables wherever possible.
Minimize the use of storage arrays and mappings.
Avoid using arrays and mappings of custom types, such as contract types and structs.
Leverage structs, particularly when dealing with related data.


Trust me i compromize the code as much as possible but still couldn't able to deploy them even on the testnet
